# How to test a void function in Dart?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, testing, flutter-test

I am new to unit tests in Dart/Flutter and I would like to write a test for a void function. When functions return something I am writing a test like this:

```
test('Gets user save', () async {
      final userSave = await mockSource!.getUserSave();
      expect(userSave!.age, equals(20));
});
```

In such a scenario like above `expect` can be used since `getUserSave` function returns a user model.

How about checking if  test passes of fails for a void/Future function like below? I can not use `expect` because it does not return a value.

```
Future<void> clearUserSave() async {
    DatabaseClient mockDBClient = MockDatabaseClientImpl();
    mockDBClient.clear();
}
```

I use `flutter_test` and `mockito` for testing.

Comment: What behavior do you *expect* to observe from the `void` function?  If it's a side effect, test for that.  If it's that the function didn't throw an exception, you can test for that too.

Answer (score 5):

testing a function  that return void  :

```
  expect(
      () async => await functionThatReturnsVoid(),
      isA<void>(),
    );
```

Answer (score 4):

Typically a `void` function will produce a side effect of some sort. When writing a test for a `void` function, I would check whatever state is effected by the `void` function before and after calling the function to be sure that the desired side effect has occurred.

In this specific case, you are calling `clear` on a `DatabaseClient`. I don't know the specifics of the `DatabaseClient` api, but I would construct a test where the client contains some data before calling `clear`, and then check that the data is no longer there after calling `clear`.

Something along the lines of this:

```dart
Future<void> clearUserSave() async {
    DatabaseClient mockDBClient = MockDatabaseClientImpl();
    mockDBClient.add(SOMEDATA);
    expect(mockDBClient.hasData, true);
    mockDBClient.clear();
    expect(mockDBClient.hasData, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add nullable variable and  assign  variable value in method, after call  method  check if this varaible isNotNull
like this:

```
test('Gets user save', () async {
  await mockSource?.getUserSave();
  final userSave=mockSource.user;
  expect(userSave,isNotNull );

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to above answers.
If you are using mokito package.
you can use thenAnswer.

```
        when(mockClass
            .voidReturningFunctionWithSomePeramerters(argThat(isNotNull)))
        .thenAnswer((_) {}); // <-- returns void.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can expect the result to be a `Future<void>`, like:

```dart
expect(
  mockSource!. clearUserSave(),
  isA<Future<void>>(),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, if result type is `void`, you can only verify expected calls.

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

import 'test_usecase_test.mocks.dart';

@GenerateNiceMocks([MockSpec<TestRepo>()])
class TestRepo {
  void doSomethingSync(String parameters) {}

  Future<void> doSomething(String parameters) async {}
}

class TestUsecase {
  final TestRepo repo;

  const TestUsecase({required this.repo});

  Future<void> execute(String parameters) async {
    repo.doSomethingSync(parameters);
    await repo.doSomething(parameters);
  }
}

void main() {
  test('test', () async {
    final repo = MockTestRepo();
    final usecase = TestUsecase(repo: repo);

    when(
      repo.doSomethingSync('parameters'),
    ).thenReturn(null);

    when(
      repo.doSomething('parameters'),
    ).thenAnswer(
      (_) => Future.value(),
    );

    await usecase.execute('parameters');

    verifyInOrder(
      [
        repo.doSomethingSync('parameters'),
        repo.doSomething('parameters'),
      ],
    );
  });
}
```